# How to make rich text clickable in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using a `Text` component to display a line of Rich Text containing two words that are clickable.

I manage to highlight the clickables, but I don't know how to make them clickable and detect their click events. Below is the text. I want to pop up a window after user clicks Platform Protocol or Privacy Policy. How can I do that? I believe this is a common requirement. I want a solution that uses Rich Text.

`You have read and agree to<color=blue><a href=\"Platform Protocol\">Platform Protocol</a></color> and <color=blue><a href=\"Privacy Policy\">Privacy Policy</a></color>`.

I have tried TextMeshPro, but I have trouble with the fonts. It even does not shows me pure ASCII characters, so I can't use it. Adding `IPointerClick` to a `Text` is feasible, but very likely to have terrible layout problems, which is the reason why I trying to use the Rich Text.

My Unity version is 2021.3.27. The 2022 version has some bugs. My UI messes around every time I open a project.

--- Update ---

Good news. I get the TextMeshPro working now. I was using the wrong TextMeshPro. I should be using TextMeshPro - Text (UI) instead of TextMeshPro - Text.

Comment: only time i had a font issue with tmpro is when i upgraded  from unity 2023.1.8 to 2023.2.whatever and the tmpro needed to reimport things cos it had changed stuff..  TMPro is  not as far as I know html, but uses some html  style tags.   however, apparently google has exactly the answer you're looking for as I searched as I didnt think tmpro, but it sort of does,  did that and hey look someone made a video how to make it do just that.

Comment: @BugFinder As I googled, TMP has a bad support for non-ascii characters. However, I used pure ascii characters and it still showed me blank squares. I have also watched some videos that teaches how to install fonts for TMP. I followed them step by step and got nothing but failure.

Comment: perhaps it has something to do with the front you are picking? however, the link portion of my comment still stands

Comment: @BugFinder I wish it were the problem of the fonts. I downloaded a go-to font from the internet and a font that needs my further operations. Both failed.

Comment: Ok so concentrate on the link portion - as yoru question here shows no non normal characters so for now, get the link working

Comment: Added two duplicates .. the first is a bit more advanced but might also be a bit more complex to configure, the second one is more simple and requires to simply split the text into the clickable and not clickable parts .. has limited layout support though of course

Comment: @derHugo Both doesn't solve my problem. They offer possible solutions but not exactly duplicate question. The first one uses TMP to do the trick, which I failed to use in my project. So I am looking for solutions that will work using `Text`. The second solution, as you said, is terrible in layout, which is the reason why I turned to the rich text.

Comment: I think the solution would be rather try and fix the font issue with TMP ... `Text` is quite legacy .. you can't just use any rich text tags they are limited down to visuals .. see [supported rich text tags in TMP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/RichTextSupportedTags.html) or same for [Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/StyledText.html) .. links (`<a>`) is definitely not among them ;)

Comment: @derHugo It doesn't need to be `<a>`, I am just looking for any tag or method that would make part of the text interactable. I really wish TMP could be an option, but I have spent a day watching videos and followed them step by step but still failed to use it due to the font problem.

Comment: There is no tag that makes a text interactive .. as said the rich text is purely for visuals. I don't think there are a lot other options beyond the linked ones tbh